# Regenerate SessionID in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please suggest how to regenerate a new Session ID in ASP.NET. If we are using SessionManager to generate a new id then it doesn't change the value of Session.SessionID. Please suggest how this can be achieved. Basically I want to have a new Session.SessionID after abandoning Session or generating NewID with SessionManager.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Take a look onto [`SessionIDManager.SaveSessionID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager.savesessionid.aspx) method, it saves a newly created session identifier to the HTTP response.:

```
SessionIDManager manager = new SessionIDManager();
var newId = manager.CreateSessionID(Context);
var isRedirected = false;
var isAdded = false;
manager.SaveSessionID(Current, newId, out isRedirected, out isAdded);
```

Comment: We tried this but the Session.SessionID is not taking the newly generated number. Thank you. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @user686021, can you extend your question with the session-related sections from the `web.config`. And also I'd like see the values of `isRedirected` and `isAdded` variables after the `manager.SaveSessionID` method call.

Comment: Look into the _CreateSessionID_ method which creates the id. SaveSessionId is only meant to attach the generated id to the response (cookies/url).

Answer (score 6):

```
//Regenerate new Session ID after login
private void RegenerateSessionId()
{
    System.Web.SessionState.SessionIDManager manager = new System.Web.SessionState.SessionIDManager();
    string oldId = manager.GetSessionID(Context);
    string newId = manager.CreateSessionID(Context);
    bool isAdd = false, isRedir = false;
    manager.SaveSessionID(Context, newId, out isRedir, out isAdd);
    HttpApplication ctx = (HttpApplication)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance;
    HttpModuleCollection mods = ctx.Modules;
    System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule ssm = (SessionStateModule)mods.Get("Session");
    System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] fields = ssm.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    SessionStateStoreProviderBase store = null;
    System.Reflection.FieldInfo rqIdField = null, rqLockIdField = null, rqStateNotFoundField = null;
    foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo field in fields)
    {
        if (field.Name.Equals("_store")) store = (SessionStateStoreProviderBase)field.GetValue(ssm);
        if (field.Name.Equals("_rqId")) rqIdField = field;
        if (field.Name.Equals("_rqLockId")) rqLockIdField = field;
        if (field.Name.Equals("_rqSessionStateNotFound")) rqStateNotFoundField = field;
    }
    object lockId = rqLockIdField.GetValue(ssm);
    if ((lockId != null) && (oldId != null)) store.ReleaseItemExclusive(Context, oldId, lockId);
    rqStateNotFoundField.SetValue(ssm, true);
    rqIdField.SetValue(ssm, newId);
}
                //get sessionId
            string SessionId = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID; //new System.Web.SessionState.SessionIDManager().GetSessionID(Context);
```

Comment: The other solutions are refreshing the session, but i am always unable to successfully login. This solution did work for me, but i don't know really how. Is it possible to shade some light in regard to what exactly are those reflection (kind of 'hacky') calls useful for?

Answer (score 3):

We used Alex's solution but initially it did not work, the original sessionID returned and the newly generated sessionID was ignored. We tried a bunch of approaches and in the end what worked was to ensure the sessionID regeneration step sits outside any login step and that there is a redirect between steps. First we destroy the session cookie, then we recreate a new sessionID and lastly we redirect to the login page. The redirect before any log in is the critical step:

```
 //delete session cookie
 Session.Abandon();
 Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));

 //create new sessionID
 SessionIDManager manager = new SessionIDManager();
 manager.RemoveSessionID(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
 var newId = manager.CreateSessionID(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
 var isRedirected = true;
 var isAdded = true;
 manager.SaveSessionID(System.Web.HttpContext.Current, newId, out isRedirected, out isAdded);

 //redirect so that the response.cookies call above actually enacts
 Response.Redirect("/account/logon");
```

Comment: Um, I think this solution misses the point. You want to change the session ID after login. Otherwise a session fixation attack is still possible, because a submission from the login page has a session ID that will be used after rights have been granted.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to **set any value in `this.Session` before redirecting**, otherwise the "empty and therefor unusable session" will be recycled.

The example code below is the condensed version of some helper functions I'm using to share some session-related info across domains. First a server-to-server call is made to set up the session id; second the user's browser is redirected to a page that will set the session id and redirect to the front page (or somewhere more relevant).

```c#
private static string CreateSessionId(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    var manager = new SessionIDManager();

    string newSessionId = manager.CreateSessionID(httpContext);

    return newSessionId;
}

public static void SetSessionId(HttpContext httpContext, string newSessionId, string redirect)
{
    var manager = new SessionIDManager();

    bool redirected;
    bool cookieAdded;

    manager.SaveSessionID(httpContext, newSessionId, out redirected, out cookieAdded);

    // Just write anything to the session, so it isn't abandoned
    httpContext.Session["WriteAnythingToTheSession"] = "Ok boss, consider it done!";

    httpContext.Response.Redirect(redirect, true);
}
```

The above was tested by setting the session id late in the normal page cycle, in `Page_Load`. Might work differently if implemented in an `HttpHandler` or something like it. Also, this was implemented in a legacy ASP.NET 2.0 application and tested locally on IIS Express - your mileage may vary.

Comment: I know im 3 years late. But if you want to send session data with this new SessionID it just get's lost from me. Like if in my action next i want to use the .Session["WriteAnythingToTheSession"] It's just null. It gets saved to the previous session.

Comment: @SomeRandomName: the point is not to *save* the value, but to *activate* the session, so to speak.

Comment: But what if you want to save data to this New session.  ?

Comment: @SomeRandomName: in this case, we set all values after the second redirect; this code is just to set the new session id on the second server. Unfortunately I can't show more code.

Answer (score 0):

I thing, we need to make in this order:

1. Generate a new SessionId with the SessionIdManager
2. Save this new SessionId
3. Set all variables attached to old session, to new session. Otherwise the session variables will be null in the new sessio

```html
//Regenerate new Session ID after login
private void RegenerateSessionId()
{
    System.Web.SessionState.SessionIDManager manager = new System.Web.SessionState.SessionIDManager();
    string oldId = manager.GetSessionID(Context);
    string newId = manager.CreateSessionID(Context);
    bool isAdd = false, isRedir = false;
    manager.SaveSessionID(Context, newId, out isRedir, out isAdd);
    HttpApplication ctx = (HttpApplication)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance;
    HttpModuleCollection mods = ctx.Modules;
    System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule ssm = (SessionStateModule)mods.Get("Session");
    System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] fields = ssm.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    SessionStateStoreProviderBase store = null;
    System.Reflection.FieldInfo rqIdField = null, rqLockIdField = null, rqStateNotFoundField = null;
    foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo field in fields)
    {
        if (field.Name.Equals("_store")) store = (SessionStateStoreProviderBase)field.GetValue(ssm);
        if (field.Name.Equals("_rqId")) rqIdField = field;
        if (field.Name.Equals("_rqLockId")) rqLockIdField = field;
        if (field.Name.Equals("_rqSessionStateNotFound")) rqStateNotFoundField = field;
    }
    object lockId = rqLockIdField.GetValue(ssm);
    if ((lockId != null) && (oldId != null)) store.ReleaseItemExclusive(Context, oldId, lockId);
    rqStateNotFoundField.SetValue(ssm, true);
    rqIdField.SetValue(ssm, newId);
}
```

I tried adding this function and then calling it immediately done login, and it works for me.

Sources:

- https://ujjwaladatta.wordpress.com/2016/11/23/regenerating-sessionid-in-asp-net/
- https://thedotnetlight.wordpress.com/2020/07/03/regenerate-new-session-id-after-login/